# number of subarrays whose minimum element is a specific given number

Tags: c++, algorithm, arrays

Given an array , I want to find the number of all subarrays whose minimum element is x .
Where x is a given number which might or might be not present in the array or multiple occurrences of the number x may occur in the array . 
O(n) implementation would be preferred.

Comment: The usual questions - Have you tried to solve this problem yourself at all? Can you show us your most successful attempt, or even just share a few ideas of things you thought of that definitely won't work in trying to solve it yourself?

Comment: well the algo on which i worked failed for multiple occurrences of the given number x . I would search that number x in the array and then calculate the numbers greater than x on its right(let n such numbers are there) and the numbers greater than x on its left (let m such numbers are there). the ans would be (m+1)*(n+1)

Comment: Long contest just started on CodeChef. This question is too similar to one of its problems: [SUBMIN](http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/SUBMIN). Be prepared for more attempts to abuse SO for cheating purposes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a vector *vec* of known size *n*. Then you run over of the elements comparing for the values of *vec(i)* against *x*. Once you find an value higher that *x*, this value can be the lower bound of a set of subvectors containing *x* as the minimum value. You continue your running over the elements of *vec*, and two things can happen:

1) you find an element smaller than *x*, then this lower bound is not valid any more, and you continue your search.

2) you find *x*, so you save the relative position respect to the lower bound and continue running over the indices until you find a value smaller than *x*, so you have the upper bound. The bounds contain a set of subarrays where x is the minimum value. Count all the possible combinations.

Either you are in case 1 or 2, you continue running over the indices until you find another valid bounds, or until you reach the end of the vector.

```
int x;
std::vector<int> vec(n);
unsigned int l_bound = n; //initialize n to an invalid index
unsigned int r_bound;
unsigned int x_pos = n; //initialize x to an invalid index
unsigned int n_sub_arrays = 0;

// here we do something to assign values to vec and x

// here we count the number of subarrays
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
{
  if (vec(i) >= x)
  {
    if (l_bound == n) // if we are at the first value higher that x
    {
      l_bound = i;
      if (vec(i) == x) // if this value is already x
      {
        x_pos = i;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
     if (x_pos == n) // x is not inside the bounds
     {
       l_bound = n; // the bounds are not valid           
     }
     else
     {
       r_bound = i-1;
       n_sub_arrays += (x_pos - l_bound+1)*(r_bound-x_pos+1);
       l_bound = n;
       x_pos = n;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work only in the case of sorted array

Comment: @algorithmist I missunderstood the question at the beginning. I understood "the subarrays which first component is the value *x* ". I have update the solution.